# NavigationLInk – Adding a delay before switching to a view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have this navigation link like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: MyForm(item))
```

I want an animation to perform on the main view, where the navigation link is, before switching to MyForm.

If I do not do that, the animation I want to perform mixes with the animation performed by the NavigationLink itself, as it switch to MyForm and the result is ugly as hell.

I want to add a delay before MyForm loads, after tapping on the navigation link.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom container you can retain the same implementation as `NavigationLink`:

```
public struct DelayedNavigationLink<Destination: View, Content: View>: View {
    @State private var activate = false
    private let delay: TimeInterval
    private let content: Content
    private let destination: Destination
    public init(destination: Destination, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.destination = destination
        self.delay = 0
    }
    private init(delay: TimeInterval, destination: Destination, content: Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.destination = destination
        self.delay = delay
    }
    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                activate = true
            }
        }) {
            content
        }.background(
            NavigationLink(destination: destination, isActive: $activate) {
                Color.clear
            }
        )
    }
    public func delayed(by delay: TimeInterval) -> Self {
        DelayedNavigationLink(delay: delay, destination: destination, content: content)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        DelayedNavigationLink(destination: Text("destination")) {
            Text("Navigate")
        }.delayed(by: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: b r i l l i a n t ! THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using navigationLink like following : -

```
NavigationLink(destination: MyForm(item),isActive: $goNext,label:{}
            ).isDetailLink(false)
```

Where go next is bool value. Now create a button and delay the action

```
    Button {
       //Let's say you have to delay navigation for 3 seconds 
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            goNext = true     
       }
       //If you have different property for starting animation you can do that here as well
    } label: {
        Text("Go Next")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot have an independent button to do that. The magic have to happen when the user taps on the navigationLink alone.

Comment: @Duck, You could replace your navigation link with the button it self... Navigation link that i referred does not have any view, it's sole purpose is to navigation when bool value changes... The view you put in for user to interact in navigation link will be the same in button... Your view won't change...