# SwiftUI NavigationLink. Animation onTapGesture and delay destination loading. Possible?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a menu of NavigationLinks (with images) that animate onto the screen from the bottom  onAppear.  Navigation works as expected when tapped, the links move off to the left as the destination view moves in from the right.

I would like the NavigationLinks to animate off the screen to the top before the destination view moves in.  Is this possible with a NavigationView?

***** Edited *****

OK, same question with Buttons instead of NavigationLinks:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var moving = false
    @State private var showFirstView = false

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            
                
                VStack{
                    
                    Image("DogPhone")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(50.0)
                    
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                 Spacer()
                    
                    
                }
                
                    Button (action: { showFirstView = true }, label: {
                    
                    Image("marker")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .navigationDestination(isPresented: 
                            $showFirstView) {
                            firstView()}
                        
                })
                .offset(CGSize(width: -100.0, height: 10.0))
                .offset(y: moving ? -100 : 400)
                .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 100, 
                     damping: 8), value: moving)
                    
                    //*******  END BUTTON ONE  ********
                                    }
                }
                

                .onAppear{
                    moving.toggle()
                    
                }
                .onDisappear{
                    moving.toggle()
                }
            }
        }      
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
```

Comment: For `NavigationLink` this is probably not possible. If you use a `Button` instead, this can be done. What version of iOS are you targeting? For 16+ you should not be using `NavigationView`s.

Comment: this post could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73945061/navigationlink-adding-a-delay-before-switching-to-a-view  and this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260503/swiftui-action-when-press-on-navigationlink

Comment: - @Sweeper I tried using NavigationStack but it throws off my animation by loading the links from the leadingEdge instead of bottom.  Seemed like a bigger problem to solve :-) I would like to target the latest OS.

Comment: @Sweeper. OK, same question with Buttons instead of NavigationLinks: